# Why did Einstein think the speed of light is special?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, spacetime, speed-of-light, velocity

I had read some crazy theories about the speed of light.

I am going to explain my own understanding of "speed" to make my point.

Suppose there was an object we'll call `A` exists at position P1 in time T1. This object is to move 1 position at a time; so at time T2, `A` is in the next position P2; at time T3, it's in position P3...etc

```
T {1,2,3,...}
P {1,2,3,...}
```

Now here is the question: How would `A` have moved faster?

If `A` was to move faster, at time T2 it would've been in position P3; at time T3:P5 ...etc

The speed here is an increment of 2. It is called "faster" than this with bigger increments. Think of the set of natural numbers {1,2,3,4,5...} and the set of the odd numbers {1,3,5,...} which is a subset. The set of odd numbers grow faster because the second element of the set of odds is the 3rd of the set of natural number; the 3rd is the fifth...

Here the set of natural numbers represents time T while the set of odds represents position P:

```
T {1,2,3,...}
P {1,3,5,...}
```

Now the question: How `A` would have been slower?

if `A` was to move slower, at time T2 it would've remained in position P1 but at time T3, it would have been in position P2. So now the set of odd numbers represents time T while the set of natural numbers represents the position P.

```
T {{1,2},{3,4},{{5,6}...}  
p {  1,    2,     3...}
```

The limit to how fast the object `A` can move is the length of space, so if the length was L, at time T2 `A` would've been in the last position if it was to move at the fastest speed.

Theoretically, there is no limit to how slow it can move. There is nothing magical about light and its speed. The above logic is applicable to the speed of light and any object in theory can move faster than light.

What do you think of this?

Comment: *What do you think of this?* Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Personal theories are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. This site is for mainstream physics only. There is a standard definition of velocity and speed in mainstream physics, and a standard way of understanding why there is a maximum speed, and your way of thinking about it is non-standard.

Comment: For the universe the length of space is infinite (or close enough for these purposes) . What do you think the max speed should be in this case?

Comment: The fact that one can imagine a number higher than 3e8 m/s doesn't mean you can actually attain it. You can write expressions of negative length, or negative mass, or subzero Kelvin temperatures, or speeds above $c$, but they aren't related to the actual physical world. You're starting from the faulty assumption that A can always just "go faster" as it wishes, which completely ignores the physics of acceleration at relativistic speeds.

Comment: The length of space is definitely not infinite

Comment: *The length of space is definitely not infinite.* Current measurements are consistent with the entire universe (not the observable universe) being infinite in extent.

Comment: *I had read some crazy theories about the speed of light.* Have you read the standard theory, Special Relativity? It’s much more satisfying than the crazy ones.

Comment: infinity cannot be attained. you obviously don't understand the definition of this word. if someone tells you "i consumed infinite amount of choclate", how would you know he's a giant fool? you could ask him " so you have finished consuming infinite amount of choclate?

Comment: To address your comment to someone specific, put @<name> in your comment. We’re talking to you, but who are you talking to?

Comment: Trying to take this on good faith, I am very confused by your reasoning here. You have made some vague statements about how speed works, and then you just conclude "anything can move faster than light". But... you haven't included anything about light here, nor have you either addressed any experiments that support your claim or offered refutations of experiments that go against what you claim. Can you fill in the holes here? How does your "theory" lead to your conclusion, specifically?

Comment: @BioPhysicist I don't need to conduct experiments in the real world. My conclusions are purely logical and I believe are correct.

Comment: Aristotle tried using “logic” to understand physics. It didn’t work out very well. Your attitude ignores everything that has made science successful, i.e.  the “scientific method”. As a result, your theory is wrong and will be ignored, except by other people with what you call “crazy theories”.

Comment: @Ghoster Logic is the father of sciences

Comment: Sorry, I can’t teach you the history of science in a comment stream, so I’ll stop here.

Comment: @machine_1 No, I'm not saying you do the experiments. I'm saying what is your explanation for the experiments that validate Einstein? Your theory has no answer

Comment: If your conclusions are "purely logical" and unrelated to any "experiments in the real world," then you're not even talking about physics. If you want to ask a question about pure math or logic, we have [another site](https://math.stackexchange.com/) for that.

Answer (score 1):

To the title question: The uniqueness of the speed of light is implicit in Maxwell's equations for electromagnetism, which were already well supported by empirical data in the early 20th century. The 2nd postulate doesn't even appear explicitly until later, being superfluous for a physicist exploring the consequences of Maxwell's model.

The rest of the question is off topic for physics se, as Ghoster notes.